# ng-repeat done event not firing on tab change but works fine on refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**on-ng-repeat-done** directive is not working when I am switching tabs or performing any operation(Page not refreshing). But it works fine when I refresh page. I have below sample where we are using directive.

```
<div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li  ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 20 track by $index" on-ng-
     repeat-done="enableItem()" tabindex="0">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Directive code:

```
module.directive('onNgRepeatDone', function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  if (scope.$last) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      scope.$eval(attrs.onNgRepeatDone);
    },0);
  }
}
}
});
```

Comment: Bkoz of on tab change ng-repeat not tracking/watching any changes value in items. so may be enableItem() not triggering.

Comment: it will work, if you will trigger a function on tab change and reassign the items value as $scope.items = angular.copy($scope.items). I think it should work fine.